# How to write $A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ as a product of elementary matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm not sure where to begin w/ this one. Can someone please help?

Comment: Reduce using Gauss-Jordon and take the inverses of the elementary operations used.

Comment: Could you reduce this matrix to its reduced row echelon form? you could write each step as a matrix multiplication. Are you familiar with elementary matrices?

Comment: I'll write an answer to your question if you still cant solve it after reading my hint.

Comment: @LittleRookie thanks...trying to work it out. A little familiarity with E matrices..

Comment: Often the first question comes into mind is whether the matrix is singular or invertible? Clearly it is invertible, which means it can be written as a product of elementary matrices.

Comment: What row operations would you do to turn A into an identity matrix?
i.e. subtract 3 times row 1 from row 2.
divide that sum by 2.
etc.

Each of those operations is associated with an elementary matrix.
The product of those operations equals $A^{-1}$

And if you can build $A^{-1}$ that way, certainly you can build $A.$

Comment: Notice that the row operations that you apply onto $A$ to reduce it to $I_{2}$ are elementary matrices and you multiply them on the left of $A$, so now, you have to find their inverses.

Comment: Are you familiar with the inverses of elementary matrices?

Comment: @ Little Rookie yup I think i just about have a handle on it. Just making sure I understand the flow of the concept. Thanks so much for your help...I appreciate it greatly.

Comment: No problem. Do you want me to write the answer here so you can check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2\\ 3 & 4\end{array} \right] = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\ 3 & 1\end{array} \right] \cdot \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\ 0 & -2\end{array} \right] \cdot \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2\\ 0 & 1\end{array} \right]$

Comment: [+1] How have you found this factorization ? It looks like a diagonalization operation but is not !

Comment: They are product of elementary matrices. Recall that the inverse of an elementary matrix is also an elementary matrix and a single row operation on a matrix $A$ can be written as the left multiplication of the corresponding elementary matrix onto $A$.

Comment: Still looks like $A = L D U$ to me

Comment: @ja72 Perhaps you learn it as a way to remember the algorithm and $A=LDU$ is the formula for you to remember. However, the theory behind this is simple and in a maths SE site, we provide theory instead of just algorithm/formula.  If you want to know more about the theory, look at my comments on OP's question.